# Monoid of ideals in GAP

Tags: gap

Given a finite dimensional algebra $A$ and a set of twosided ideals $\{I_1, I_2,...,I_n \}$. Let $G$ be the monoid (or sometimes group) generated by those ideals.
Is there a way to obtain this monoid via GAP (or a package like qpa) and check what monoid it is (and wheter it is finite)?

Is there a quick way to get the maximal ideals of the algebra? (at least when its a quiver algebra, this should be easy, but I found no command for that).

Comment: Group?$\phantom{}$

Comment: Changed it to monoid.

Comment: what's the operation?

Comment: simply multiplication of twosided ideals.

Answer (score 2):

In QPA one can do the following:

```
gap> A := NakayamaAlgebra(Rationals, [3,2]);
<Rationals[<quiver with 2 vertices and 2 arrows>]/
<two-sided ideal in <Rationals[<quiver with 2 vertices and 2 arrows>]>, (1 generators)>>
gap> gens := GeneratorsOfAlgebra(A){[2..5]};
[ [(1)*v1], [(1)*v2], [(1)*a1], [(1)*a2] ]
gap> I1 := Ideal(A, gens{[2..4]});          
<two-sided ideal in <Rationals[<quiver with 2 vertices and 2 arrows>]/
    <two-sided ideal in <Rationals[<quiver with 2 vertices and 2 arrows>]>, (1 generators)>>,
  (3 generators)>
gap> I2 := Ideal(A, gens{[1,3,4]});         
<two-sided ideal in <Rationals[<quiver with 2 vertices and 2 arrows>]/
    <two-sided ideal in <Rationals[<quiver with 2 vertices and 2 arrows>]>, (1 generators)>>,
  (3 generators)>
gap> ProductSpace(I1,I1);                   
<algebra of dimension 4 over Rationals>
gap> ProductSpace(I1,I1) = I1;
true
gap> ProductSpace(I1,I2);     
<vector space of dimension 2 over Rationals>
gap> ProductSpace(I2,ProductSpace(I1,I2));
<vector space of dimension 1 over Rationals>
```

All the maximal ideals are generated by all the vertices except one and all the arrows. So two vertices give two maximal ideals `I1` and `I2`.  The product of two ideals can be computed, for example, the product of `I1` and `I2` is `ProductSpace(I1,I2)`. Using the above commands one can produce code to generate more ideals.

I hope that this is helpful.

Best regards, the QPA-team.